# swagger3 Pattern operation with springboot3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

Its a springboot app with OAS3 .

There is a controller which accepts id as Query parameter.

```
@RequestMapping("/detail")
public class Controller {
@Operation(
        tags = "Shop APIs",
        summary ="Find Shop detail",
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "successful operation",
                content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = FacilitiesResponse.class)))
        },
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(in =  ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "id",required = true, style = ParameterStyle.DEFAULT,explode=Explode.FALSE,schema = @Schema(pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}")),
            
        }
    )
    @GetMapping()
    public Flux<DetailResponse> getDetail(final @RequestParam Optional<String> id){

    //return statement 
}
}
```

I have a requirement that query param -"id" accepts multiple comma separated value & each id follow REGEX [a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}. i.e each should be 5-15 in length and should be consisted of a-z, A-Z and 0-9 only
eg 2RXB859H4IWSF,2RXB859H4IWSI

for this I have added explode as false and pattern as shown below.

```
parameters = {
            @Parameter(in =  ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "id",required = true,style = ParameterStyle.DEFAULT,explode=Explode.FALSE,schema = @Schema(pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}")),
            
        }
```

But when I try from swagger what I observed :

1. it is just checking pattern upto 5 character only i.e id value as @ is not allowed is correct but if I provide @12345 is being allowed which is not correct
2. 2RXB859H4IWSF]},##2RXB859H4IWSF as id value is being treated as single value.  It should be treated as two different id and pattern should be applied on both of them separately.
3. even 2RXB859H4IWSF]} as id value is being allowed which should not be. Its not following pattern that I have added above

Answer (score 0):

Please modify the regular expression as below.

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}$`

code

```java
            @Parameter(in =  ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "id",required = true,style = ParameterStyle.DEFAULT,explode=Explode.FALSE,schema = @Schema(pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}$"))
```